# mobngoDB: set sequential value by group

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with documents that have an index property indicating their order and a group property:

```
{
    "item": "A1",
    "group": "A",
    "index": 1
}
{
    "item": "A2",
    "group": "A",
    "index": 2
}
{
    "item": "B1",
    "group": "B",
    "index": 3
}
{
    "item": "B2",
    "group": "B",
    "index": 4
}
{
    "item": "C1",
    "group": "C",
    "index": 5
} 
{
    "item": "C2",
    "group": "C",
    "index": 6
}
```

Now a want to assign new index values based on an ordering of the groups: e.g. [B,C,A] should result in:

```
{
    "item": "B1",
    "group": "B",
    "index": 1
}
{
    "item": "B2",
    "group": "B",
    "index": 2
}
{
    "item": "C1",
    "group": "C",
    "index": 3
} 
{
    "item": "C2",
    "group": "C",
    "index": 4
} 
{
    "item": "A1",
    "group": "A",
    "index": 5
}
{
    "item": "A2",
    "group": "A",
    "index": 6
}
```

Is there a way to do this in one update statement or do I have to run a query for each document seperately? It is also important that the initial ordering within a group does not get changed.

Comment: Of course this cannot be performed in a single update statement since all documents are going to receive a new "index" value, and that is different for every document. [Bulk Operations](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) are your best method for updating. The order here sees to follow a basic rule for sorting as `{ "group": 1, "item": 1 }`, being first "group" then "item" in ascending order. You might also want to consider what the purpose of updating this index is, if simple sorting rules would suffice.

Comment: @BlakesSeven using a simple sort does not apply unfortunately. My actual data is not as structured as my example above. The item and group values may contain any value and the user is later also able to manually reorder the documents. (i.e. items with the same group may eventually not stay together within the entire collection). So I guess bulk operations would be my best bet. Is there a signification boost in performance compared to update each document individually without using a bulk operation?

Comment: The basic concept of "Bulk" is that a "batch" of operations ( there is an internal protocol limit of 1000, but this is handled transparently. Still best to keep your batches that size or smaller anyway ) is sent to the server in one request, and returns one response. Without using "bulk" operations, each update is a request to the server where you are typically also waiting for the response. So yes, there is a significant reduction in overhead by using this.